# Highlight every word in long text when clicked on

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to record every word from a paragraph of text when it is clicked on. However, I would also like to provide visual feedback to the user when they have clicked on a word. This [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574782/set-event-listener-on-every-word-in-a-long-text) has been very helpful. But I don't seem to be understand how to add a class to it. I've marked the areas where my added code is not working:

```js
var book = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu eum eros vitae persequeris, laudem possit nam ex. Labore eloquentiam per an. Sit ex omnesque interpretaris, habeo tantas eos ad, ea eos ludus inciderint. Facete tritani pro ei, vim evertitur liberavisse ex. Ridens indoctum duo cu, est utamur aliquando expetendis ne. Cum nusquam definiebas ex, id esse neglegentur cum, eu libris bonorum volumus vis. Ius et quis omnis graeco, no his nullam perpetua dissentiet. No vix possim scripserit consequuntur, te mnesarchum philosophia sed. Ne mea putent iudicabit, in eam ipsum viris dicunt. Eum amet accommodare ex, sint malis adversarium at qui.'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { book: '' },
  methods: {
    doSomething(e) {
      var content = e.target.textContent
      var pos = window.getSelection().anchorOffset
      content = content
        .substring(0, content.indexOf(' ', pos))
        .trim()
      content = content
        .substr(content.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1)
        .replace(/[.,:;!?()+-]/g, '')
        // not working code
        .add('highlight')

      console.log(content)
    }
  },
  created() {
    // load external data
    this.book = book
  }
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p @click="doSomething" v-html="book"></p>
</div>
```

I would like each word to remain highlighted when clicked on. For example, if you click on "Lorem ipsum dolor" all 3 words should be highlighted in yellow. Preferably, if clicked again, they would be unhighlighted too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the mentioned [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574782/set-event-listener-on-every-word-in-a-long-text) in your post and came up with the following solution.

1. Use the solution that adds `spans` to each word
2. In the event handler, you can check if there exists any style. For our case, we can check if there is a `color` property ie `event.target.style.color`
3. If it does exist then you know that this has been clicked and you can revert the color to your choice
4. If it doesn't exist then you know it's the first time clicking it and can set the color to your choice

```js
var page = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu eum eros vitae persequeris, laudem possit nam ex. Labore eloquentiam per an. Sit ex omnesque interpretaris, habeo tantas eos ad, ea eos ludus inciderint. Facete tritani pro ei, vim evertitur liberavisse ex. Ridens indoctum duo cu, est utamur aliquando expetendis ne. Cum nusquam definiebas ex, id esse neglegentur cum, eu libris bonorum volumus vis. Ius et quis omnis graeco, no his nullam perpetua dissentiet. No vix possim scripserit consequuntur, te mnesarchum philosophia sed. Ne mea putent iudicabit, in eam ipsum viris dicunt. Eum amet accommodare ex, sint malis adversarium at qui.'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    page: ''
  },
  computed: {
    pageContent() {
      return this.page.replace(/\b(\w+?)\b/g, '<span>$1</span>')
    }
  },
  methods: {
    doSomething(e) {
      if (e.target.style.color) {
        //Revert back to black text
        e.target.style = 'color: black;';
      } else {
        //Change text color to yellow
        e.target.style = 'color: yellow;';
      }
      console.log(e.target.textContent);
    }
  },
  created() {
    // load external data
    this.page = page
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p @click="doSomething" v-html="pageContent"></p>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.9/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

*Note : This code was not thought by me. It was copy-pasted from the above stackoverflow link. Just modified it for the scenario :)*

Also, I don't know jack shit about `vue` lol

Answer (score 0):

Split your text into words using `\b` regex, make each word its own , and then highlight those

[Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#__DEV__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)

```js
<script>
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  data: () => ({
    book: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu eum eros vitae persequeris, laudem possit nam ex. Labore eloquentiam per an. Sit ex omnesque interpretaris, habeo tantas eos ad, ea eos ludus inciderint. Facete tritani pro ei, vim evertitur liberavisse ex. Ridens indoctum duo cu, est utamur aliquando expetendis ne. Cum nusquam definiebas ex, id esse neglegentur cum, eu libris bonorum volumus vis. Ius et quis omnis graeco, no his nullam perpetua dissentiet. No vix possim scripserit consequuntur, te mnesarchum philosophia sed. Ne mea putent iudicabit, in eam ipsum viris dicunt. Eum amet accommodare ex, sint malis adversarium at qui.',
    selectedWord: 'cu'
  }),
  computed: {
    words() {
      // split by `\b` - the "word border"
      // [ "Lorem", " ", "ipsum", " ", "dolor", " ", "sit", " ", "amet", ", ", ...]
      return this.book.match(/\b.+?\b/g)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    select(word) {
      this.selectedWord = word
    },
    isSelected(word) {
      return word.toLowerCase() === this.selectedWord.toLowerCase()
    }
  }
})
</script>

<template>
  <input v-model="selectedWord">
  <p>
    <span v-for="w of words" @click="select(w)" :class="{ 'selected-word': isSelected(w) }">
      {{ w }}
    </span>
  </p>
</template>

<style scoped>
.selected-word {
  background: yellow;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This may have problems if your text is measured in megabytes, but otherwise it's much simplier then alternate solutions

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the absolute `anchorOffset` relative to the closest paragraph element and find then start/end indices to figure out which word was clicked. Make sure the indices are sorted from end-to-start, so that replacements do not shift substring positions.

You can store each start/end position as a state and re-render the original text, with the replaced words (highlighted).

```js
const book = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu eum eros vitae persequeris, laudem possit nam ex. Labore eloquentiam per an. Sit ex omnesque interpretaris, habeo tantas eos ad, ea eos ludus inciderint. Facete tritani pro ei, vim evertitur liberavisse ex. Ridens indoctum duo cu, est utamur aliquando expetendis ne. Cum nusquam definiebas ex, id esse neglegentur cum, eu libris bonorum volumus vis. Ius et quis omnis graeco, no his nullam perpetua dissentiet. No vix possim scripserit consequuntur, te mnesarchum philosophia sed. Ne mea putent iudicabit, in eam ipsum viris dicunt. Eum amet accommodare ex, sint malis adversarium at qui.'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { book: '', indices: [] },
  methods: {
    highlightWord({ currentTarget: { textContent } }) {
      const { endIndex } = getAbsoluteSelection();
      const cursor = findWordBounds(textContent, endIndex);
      if (cursor) {
        toggleItem(this.indices, cursor, compareCursors);
        this.book = applyHighlights(book, this.indices);
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.book = book;
  }
});

const findWordBounds = (content, pos) => {
  let startIndex = pos, endIndex = pos;
  while (startIndex > 0 && /\w/.test(content[startIndex])) {
    startIndex--;
  }
  while (endIndex < content.length && /\w/.test(content[endIndex])) {
    endIndex++;
  }
  if (content[startIndex] === ' ') {
    startIndex++;
  }
  const word = content.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
  if (word.trim().length === 0) return null;
  return { startIndex, endIndex };
};

const toggleItem = (list, item, comparator) => {
  const foundIndex = list.findIndex((curr) =>
    comparator(curr, item) === 0);
  if (foundIndex !== -1) {
    list.splice(foundIndex, 1);
  } else {
    list.push(item);
    list.sort(comparator);
  }
};

const replaceAtIndex = (content, startIndex, endIndex, replacer) => {
  const head = content.substring(0, startIndex);
  const word = content.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
  const tail = content.substring(endIndex);
  return head + replacer(word) + tail;
};

const highlightWord = (word) =>
  `<span class="highlight">${word}</span>`;

const applyHighlights = (content, indices) => {
  let html = content;
  for (let { startIndex, endIndex } of indices) {
    html = replaceAtIndex(html, startIndex, endIndex, highlightWord);
  }
  return html;
};

// Sort largest to smallest
const compareCursors = (a, b) =>
  b.endIndex - a.endIndex || b.startIndex - a.startIndex;

// Get absolute anchor offset relative to closest paragraph element.
// Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66336616/1762224
function getAbsoluteSelection() {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const start = selection.anchorOffset;
  const end = selection.extentOffset;
  const anchorNode = selection.anchorNode;
  const extentNode = selection.extentNode;
  const startIndex = calculateOffset(anchorNode, start);
  const endIndex = calculateOffset(extentNode, end);
  return { startIndex, endIndex };
}
function calculateOffset(child, relativeOffset) {
  let parent = child.parentElement;
  if (parent.tagName !== 'P') {
    parent = parent.closest('p');
    child = child.parentElement;
  }
  const children = [];
  for (let c of parent.childNodes) {
    if (c === child) break;
    children.push(c);
  }
  return relativeOffset + children.reduce((a, c) => a + c.textContent.length, 0);
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#app > p {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p @click="highlightWord" v-html="book"></p>
</div>
```

Here is a demonstration of relative vs absolute selection anchor position. The selection is always relative to the closest element.

```js
const infoEl = document.querySelector('#info')

document.querySelector('.outer')
    .addEventListener('click', updateOffset);

updateInfo(-1, -1);

function updateOffset(e) {
    const outer = e.target.currentTarget; // Outer
  const inner = e.target.target; // Selection target (relative)
    const relativeOffset = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
  const absoluteOffset = getAbsoluteSelection().endIndex;
  updateInfo(relativeOffset, absoluteOffset);
}

function updateInfo(relativeOffset, absoluteOffset) {
    infoEl.textContent = `
    Relative Offset: ${relativeOffset}
    Absolute Offset: ${absoluteOffset}
  `.trim().replace(/^\s+/gm, '');
}

// Based on: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66336616/1762224
function getAbsoluteSelection() {
  const selection = window.getSelection();
  const start = selection.anchorOffset;
  const end = selection.extentOffset;
  const anchorNode = selection.anchorNode;
  const extentNode = selection.extentNode;
  const startIndex = calculateOffset(anchorNode, start);
  const endIndex = calculateOffset(extentNode, end);
  return { startIndex, endIndex };
}

function calculateOffset(child, relativeOffset) {
  let parent = child.parentElement;
  if (parent.tagName !== 'P') {
    parent = parent.closest('p');
    child = child.parentElement;
  }
  const children = [];
  for (let c of parent.childNodes) {
    if (c === child) break;
    children.push(c);
  }
  return relativeOffset + children.reduce((a, c) => a + c.textContent.length, 0);
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #222;
  color: #EEE;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.outer {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.outer:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.inner {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#info {
  width: 10rem;
  min-height: 2rem;
  padding: 0.25rem;
  border: thin solid grey;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<p class="outer">Hello <span class="inner">this</span> is <span class="inner">simply</span> a <span class="inner">test</span></p>
<div id="info"></div>
```

Here is a modified version of Halapgos1's solution. I simplified the logic to simply toggle the `.highlight` class on the event target element.

```js
const page = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cu eum eros vitae persequeris, laudem possit nam ex. Labore eloquentiam per an. Sit ex omnesque interpretaris, habeo tantas eos ad, ea eos ludus inciderint. Facete tritani pro ei, vim evertitur liberavisse ex. Ridens indoctum duo cu, est utamur aliquando expetendis ne. Cum nusquam definiebas ex, id esse neglegentur cum, eu libris bonorum volumus vis. Ius et quis omnis graeco, no his nullam perpetua dissentiet. No vix possim scripserit consequuntur, te mnesarchum philosophia sed. Ne mea putent iudicabit, in eam ipsum viris dicunt. Eum amet accommodare ex, sint malis adversarium at qui.'

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { page: '' },
  computed: {
    pageContent() {
      return this.page.replace(/\b(\w+)\b/g, '<span>$1</span>');
    }
  },
  methods: {
    highlightWord({ target }) {
      target.classList.toggle('highlight');
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.page = page;
  }
})
```

```css
.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}

#app > p:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p @click="highlightWord" v-html="pageContent"></p>
</div>
```